# makefile with mex-project: `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object

Tags: c, matlab, makefile, mex

I have a c-code which I can compile using makefile and run. Now, I want to convert it to mex file which I would like to compile using corresponding makefile. However, my makefile for mex code is not working. I would appreciate if someone can guide me.

I am working on **64 bit** system.

Structure of both C-codes and mex codes:

```
C-codes                                Mex Code
Test_tsnnls.c <--Main defined         Test_tsnnls_MEX.c <--mex defined here
Include_4_TSNNLS.h                    Include_4_TSNNLS.h
Include_4_TSNNLS.c                    Include_4_TSNNLS.c
```

Makefile (C-project) works:

```
CXX       = gcc
FLAGS     = 
CFLAGS    = "-m64"   ## "-m32"
INCLUDE_TSNNLS  = -I/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3 -I/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls  -I/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/taucs_basic

#################### ALL TSNNLS lib related ##########################
## this is where all object file (*.o) generated by tsnnls library makefile are located.
tsnnl_PATH = /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/

# Here is a Make Macro that uses the backslash to extend to multiple lines.
OBJS_tsnnls0 =  libtsnnls_la-taucs_malloc.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_order.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_ops.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_vec_base.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_complex.o libtsnnls_la-colamd.o \
    libtsnnls_la-amdbar.o libtsnnls_la-amdexa.o \
    libtsnnls_la-amdtru.o libtsnnls_la-genmmd.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_timer.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_sn_llt.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_base.o libtsnnls_la-tlsqr.o \
    libtsnnls_la-tsnnls.o libtsnnls_la-lsqr.o

 ## adding "$(OBJS_PATH)" to each word in "$(OBJS)"
# which in our case is basically to add the same folder in front of all "*.o" object files.
OBJS_tsnnls = $(addprefix $(tsnnl_PATH), $(OBJS_tsnnls0)) 

# Libraries for tsnnls
STLIB_tsnnls    = /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/lib/linux/libtaucs.a 
LIBS_tsnnls     = -largtable2 -llapack -lblas -lquadmath -lm

########################################################################
TARGET_WO_EXTN =   Test_tsnnls
TARGET         =   $(TARGET_WO_EXTN)
LIBS           =   $(LIBS_tsnnls)   $(STLIB_tsnnls)
INCLUDE        =   $(INCLUDE_TSNNLS)
REBUILDABLES   =   *.o          $(TARGET) 

all : $(TARGET)
    echo All done

clean : 
    rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)   
    echo Clean done

Include_4_TSNNLS.o: Include_4_TSNNLS.c
    $(CXX) -c -o Include_4_TSNNLS.o Include_4_TSNNLS.c

$(TARGET_WO_EXTN).o: $(TARGET_WO_EXTN).c
    $(CXX) -c -o $(TARGET_WO_EXTN).o  $(TARGET_WO_EXTN).c

# Final linking
$(TARGET) : $(OBJS_tsnnls)   $(TARGET_WO_EXTN).o   Include_4_TSNNLS.o $(LIBS)
    $(CXX) -g -o $@ $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $^
```

Makefile (mex project) DOES NOT work:

```
MEXSUFFIX  = mexa64
MATLABHOME = /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b
MEX        = mex
CXX        = gcc
CFLAGS     = -fPIC -pthread -DMX_COMPAT_32 \
               -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE

INCLUDE_Matlab  = -I$(MATLABHOME)/extern/include
MEXFLAGS    = -cxx CC='$(CXX)' CXX='$(CXX)' LD='$(CXX)'

INCLUDE_TSNNLS  = -I/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3 -I/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls  -I/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/taucs_basic

#################### ALL TSNNLS lib related ##########################
## this is where all object file (*.o) generated by tsnnls library makefile are located.
tsnnl_PATH = /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/

# Here is a Make Macro that uses the backslash to extend to multiple lines.
OBJS_tsnnls0 =  libtsnnls_la-taucs_malloc.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_order.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_ops.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_vec_base.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_complex.o libtsnnls_la-colamd.o \
    libtsnnls_la-amdbar.o libtsnnls_la-amdexa.o \
    libtsnnls_la-amdtru.o libtsnnls_la-genmmd.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_timer.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_sn_llt.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_base.o libtsnnls_la-tlsqr.o \
    libtsnnls_la-tsnnls.o libtsnnls_la-lsqr.o

 ## adding "$(OBJS_PATH)" to each word in "$(OBJS)"
# which in our case is basically to add the same folder in front of all "*.o" object files.
OBJS_tsnnls = $(addprefix $(tsnnl_PATH), $(OBJS_tsnnls0)) 

# Libraries for tsnnls
STLIB_tsnnls    = /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/lib/linux/libtaucs.a 
LIBS_tsnnls     = -largtable2 -llapack -lblas -lquadmath -lm

########################################################################
TARGET_WO_EXTN =  Test_tsnnls_Mex
TARGET         = $(TARGET_WO_EXTN).$(MEXSUFFIX)
LIBS           = $(LIBS_tsnnls)     $(STLIB_tsnnls)
INCLUDE        = $(INCLUDE_Matlab)  $(INCLUDE_TSNNLS)
REBUILDABLES   = *.o            $(TARGET)  

all : $(TARGET)
    echo All done

clean : 
    rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)   
    echo Clean done

Include_4_TSNNLS.o:  Include_4_TSNNLS.c
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $^
##  $(CXX) -c -o Include_4_TSNNLS.o Include_4_TSNNLS.c

$(TARGET_WO_EXTN).o: $(TARGET_WO_EXTN).c
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $^

# Final linking
$(TARGET): $(OBJS_tsnnls)   $(TARGET_WO_EXTN).o   Include_4_TSNNLS.o $(LIBS)
    $(MEX) $(MEXFLAGS) $(LIBS) -output $(TARGET_WO_EXTN) $^
```

Errors that I get

```
dkumar@dkumar-Precision-WorkStation-T7500 ~/Mex_Codes_DKU/Using_tsnnls_DKU_copy_MEX/Pure_Mex $ make
cc -fPIC -pthread -DMX_COMPAT_32 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE   -c -o Test_tsnnls_Mex.o Test_tsnnls_Mex.c
gcc -c -o Include_4_TSNNLS.o Include_4_TSNNLS.c
In file included from Include_4_TSNNLS.c:1:0:
Include_4_TSNNLS.h:72:15: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [enabled by default]
   extern enum STYPE;
               ^
mex -cxx CC='gcc' CXX='gcc' LD='gcc' -largtable2 -llapack -lblas -lquadmath -lm     /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/lib/linux/libtaucs.a  -output Test_tsnnls_Mex /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_malloc.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_order.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_ops.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_vec_base.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_complex.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-colamd.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-amdbar.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-amdexa.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-amdtru.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-genmmd.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_timer.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_sn_llt.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_base.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-tlsqr.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-tsnnls.o /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-lsqr.o Test_tsnnls_Mex.o Include_4_TSNNLS.o /usr/local/lib/libargtable2.so /usr/lib/liblapack.so /usr/lib/libblas.so /usr/lib/libquadmath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/lib/linux/libtaucs.a
Building with 'g++'.
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.2'. The version of gcc is not supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of currently supported compilers see: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.2-19ubuntu1)'. The version of gcc is not supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of currently supported compilers see: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.
/usr/bin/ld: /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_order.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_order.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [Test_tsnnls_Mex.mexa64] Error 255
```

I think that I am already compiling with -fPIC.
My understanding is that  `$(OBJS_tsnnls)` may not properly included in my mex project.

OR, 
issue could be with 32-bit vs 64 bit platform [Stackoveflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637551/relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-rodata-while-compiling-on-64-bit-platform). I have no idea how to fix this.

Any help would be so very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have another look at the error messages - the part with the call to `mex`:

```
mex -cxx CC='gcc' CXX='gcc' LD='gcc' -largtable2 -llapack -lblas -lquadmath -lm
```

While you have modified the `CFLAGS` Makefile variable to include `-fPIC`, you didn't ensure it was being passed to `mex` (the very bottom command in your Makefile).  You could modify `MEXFLAGS`.  This should cover all bases:

```
MEXFLAGS = -v -cxx CC='$(CXX)' CXX='$(CXX)' CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' CXXFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' LD='$(CXX)'
```

You don't need both `CC` and `CXX` (probably just `CXX` since it's compiling as C++).  Also, add the `-v` flag to see what the failing g++ command was.

It is interesting to use `mex` just to link object files instead of also do the compiling.  If I understand the goal here, it's to link object files compiled as C, and the approach was to instruct `mex` to compile as C++, but setting `CXX=gcc`, forcing it to use the C frontend.  Should work I guess, but it seems rather contorted.

Comment: I did modified MEXFLAGS as you suggested:  ` MEXFLAGS  =  -fPIC -v -cxx CC='$(CXX)' CXX='$(CXX)' CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' CXXFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' LD='$(CXX)'` But, that gives me the error that `........................ibm.so /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/lib/linux/libtaucs.a
Verbose mode is on.
Unknown MEX argument '-fPIC'.
make: *** [Test_tsnnls_Mex.mexa64] Error 255
 `. Does this mean that I should recompile object files in `OBJS_tsnnls0 ` with `-fPIC` option?

Comment: My understanding of makefile is at the beginner level and I understand very little about mex compiler option.  I modified this makefile (mex project)[link](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~pcarbo/mex-tutorial/). What I want is: to compile all *.c using gcc compiler and then link it using mex file. It works if I remove all obj files included via `OBJS_tsnnls0` and also do not call corresponding function from mex. MEXFLAGS appear very strange to me, particularly part which `CC='$(CXX)' CXX='$(CXX)' CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' CXXFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)'  LD='$(CXX)' ` Could you please explain what is being done here?

Comment: @GarimaSingh I did not make that suggestion.  See my answer again.  There is no `-fPIC` in `MEXFLAGS`; it is in `CFLAGS`.  Also, in `mex` it will only use one of `CXX` or `CC` and one of `CXXFLAGS` or `CFLAGS`, depending on if it is being compiled as C++ or C.  It looks like `-cxx` tells it to compile as C++, but I can't find any docs about this switch.  Do some experimentation and look at the output when using the `-v` flag to figure this out.