# compilation of Qt 5 fails under make in debian64

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, qtnetwork, qsslsocket

I tried to make qt 5.4.1 with openSsl configuration but i got some errors during make it.

I configured it as bellow :

```
OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto' ./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -debug-and-release -nomake tests -openssl-linked -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

and then `make`.

the last 10 line of output is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a(s2_srvr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../../lib/libQt5Network.so.5.4.1] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/l/software/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/src/network'
make[2]: *** [sub-network-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/l/software/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/src'
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/l/software/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase'
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: ... how did you compile OpenSSL? Seems like you didn't configure it properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relocation R\_X86\_64\_32S against \`.rodata' ... While compiling on 64-bit platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637551/relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-rodata-while-compiling-on-64-bit-platform). Configure OpenSSL with the `shared` option to ensure `-fPIC` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link a static library into a shared library on x86_64, the static library needs to be compiled with `-fPIC`. You could now build OpenSSL manually with -fPIC set, but that'd be a bit of a hassle.

I'd suggest to configure Qt with `-openssl` instead of `-openssl-linked`. Then SSL won't be linked at compile time but loaded dynamically (`dlopen`) at runtime. It's the usual way to handle OpenSSL in Qt, also because of the incompabilities between the OpenSSL and GPL licenses.