# c++ Linker error 'relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' Linking CXX shared library libsrt.so

Tags: c++, linker, g++, shared-libraries, libcrypto

I am getting this error everytime I run make.If I copy libsrt.so from another directory,then it gets compiled. Anyone has idea?

```
Linking CXX shared library libsrt.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(aes_misc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/srt.dir/build.make:763: recipe for target 'libsrt.so.1.2.0' failed
```

Comment: did you try to compile it with `-fPIC` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69005262/778517

Answer (score 1):

what the error message is telling you is that the linking of `libsrt.so` failed because you tried to link `libsrt.so` with `libcrypto.a` but `libcrypto.a` wasn't complied with `-fPIC`.

`-fPIC` is a complier flag that changes the code generation to production position indepandent code (PIC) which is required for shared object because the linker doesn't know where the shared object will be loaded.

to fix this issue you can:

- recomplie `libcrypto.a` with `-fPIC` if you complied it yourself
- use the shared object of libcrypto `libcrypto.so` if you received compiled binairies

in your case libcrypto being part of openssl using `libcrypto.so` is much better

Comment: and how can we compile libcrypto.a with -fPIC?

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh recompling libcrypto.a with -fPIC is only really applicable if you build libcrypto.a and can add the flag.

Comment: I can use the shared objects but I have to copy them everytime I run make

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a shared version of `libcrypto` - `libcrypto.so`. And link against that (the linker does that automatically when `.so` is present).